# MVC POST action with 100 row of List is slow (performance)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Currently working on ASP.NET-MVC5 project.

I have a `View` with `list` as model. It took like 5 seconds to hit my `[HttpPost]` Controller. Any idea that might help the performance or is this normal in MVC?

My View :

```
@model list<TempViewModel>
......
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Action Menu</td>
            <td>Controller Name</td>
            <td>Category</td>
            <td>Group Desc</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    @{
        for(int x = 0;counter < model.count-1;counter++){
    }

    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[x].ActionName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[x].ActionName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[x].ControllerName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[x].ControllerName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[x].Category)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[x].Category)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[x].GroupDesc)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[x].GroupDesc)
        </td>
    </tr>
    .....
    <input type="submit" />
```

My Model :

```
public class TempViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public char Category { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string GroupDesc { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SyncActionMenu(List<TempViewModel> model)
{
     //do something with model here
}
```

Comment: You don't need `()` brackets for attributes.

Comment: @warheat1990 are you using store process for get data ? cos store process tack exact 5 sec for process itself

Comment: @sourabhdevpura: what do you mean store process? Stored procedure? I have no problem with getting the data from DB. But the problem is when I hit the submit button, for example : if I empty one of these field and hit submit, it takes like 5 seconds (page freeze) before the validation message show up.

Comment: @warheat1990 it look like your server responding slow . cos every time you hit the submit button a new request sent to server . and those are the wait two way requested like request and response

Comment: @sourabhdevpura: any idea how to improve this? Because I'm testing inside localhost.

Comment: Your code wont even work - it would need to be `for(int x = 0 ;x < Model.Count; i++) { @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[x].ActionName) ...}`. Are you really editing 100 rows at a time?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Sorry my code is originally from `VB` and I had to convert it real quick to `C#` because `VB` section is dead town. But yeah, I'm editing 100 rows at a time.

Comment: @StephenMuecke 1st check and tell me what happens with 1 row . then i will give you tell what you should do for improvement

Comment: @sourabhdevpura, Sorry, but I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: with 1 row, it's instant. It starts taking performance hit around 50 rows (took like 2 secs).

Comment: @warheat1990 ok then replace your for loop with lambda expression . https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx . this will process faster then normal loop

Comment: @sourabhdevpura Stephen Muecke is not the person asking this question.

Comment: @sourabhdevpura, It's not my question! I think your meaning to respond to warheat1990

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry :)

Comment: SO could use a better UI for replying, everyone is confused who ask who haha.

Comment: @warheat1990 Comments are not meant for extended discussions. That's what [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) is for; if it seems hard to follow a comment "thread", that's probably by design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're saying about page freeze before you see validation error, this mean that your unobtrusive jquery validation do a lot of work.

You can disable it. Or decrease amount of editable row to <50.

if you disable it, you still be able to check your model valid state in controller post action by checking `ModelState.IsValid`and returning model back.